# Switching between two completely independent circuits

Tags: switches, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Background: I have built a 2S 7.4V battery out of two 18650 batteries. I have some TP4056 (5V 1A Micro-USB) charging modules lying around. I would like to use these the TP4056 modules (one per 18650) to charge the batteries but from the information I've found, having any connection between the two batteries is not a good idea while charging.

Therefore, I'm looking for a switch that would only switch on one circuit at a time. Either the serial connection b/w the batteries, or the charging input to the TP4056s.

Something like this:
[image]

What exactly is such a switch called (if it exists)? Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Excuse my noobness.

**Update:**

With a DPDT switch (thanks @Solar Mike!), does the following circuit make sense?
  [image]

Comment: Double pole double throw switch (dpdt) seems to be what you describe.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like that's what i need! I've updated my question with a circuit that I think should work. Do you think so too? :)

Comment: You can connect eg top of one cell and bottom of other cell permanently to suppy + and - respectively and inly switch the opposite ends.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOWd3p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's proposal redrawn.*

With SW1 in position shown BAT2+ will be shorted to U1's BAT- which according to the [TP4056 datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) is supposed to be connected to ground so the arrangement is likely to have a very unhappy ending.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIlcPs.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A circuit with less potential problems. SW1 is a 3-pole switch.*

- SW1b and 1c allows switching of BAT1 in series with BAT2 or in parallel with U1.
- SW1a prevents BAT2 receiving charge while BAT1 is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please guide me to a small form factor 3-pole switch that can handle upto 15A?

Comment: No, sorry. I would have to look it up for you.

Comment: That would be great, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I'm sure it would, but I'm not going to do it for you. That's your job!

Comment: Hah! Sorry I misunderstood you. I've tried but haven't really found something small enough. [This](https://bit.ly/2LFLMFv): for example would be an option. But I can't seem to find the exact dimensions for it. 

I would greatly appreciate some help if possible :)